# Agregar salto de línea entre una imagen y un texto en VBS

Tags: vbscript

Tengo el siguiente script el cual agrega firma a los correos en **Outlook**:

```
.....
...


 Set objShape = objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture("\\blabla\blabla\blabla\blabla\blabla\" & strlogin2 & ".jpg") 

 url = "http://url.com.mx/assets/aviso.pdf"
 objSelection.Font.Italic = true
 objSelection.Font.Size = 09
 objSelection.TypeText "El Aviso de Privacidad de XXXXXX, está disponible en "
 Set objLink = objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add(objSelection.Range, url)
 objSelection.TypeText ", es aplicable a todos los Titulares de Datos Personales obtenidos por la Empresa, a través de cualquier medio físico o electrónico y para los fines que se hace referencia en el mismo."
  objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(255,102,0)
  objLink.Range.Font.Name = "Calibri" 
  objLink.Range.Font.Size = 09 
  objLink.Range.Font.Bold = true 
  objSelection.Font.Bold = true
 objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(105,105,105)
 objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(105,105,105)


 objSelection.TypeParagraph()

 Set objSelection = objDoc.Range()
 objSignatureEntries.Add "Firma Corporativa XXXX", objSelection
 objSignatureObject.NewMessageSignature = "Firma Corporativa XXXXXX"
 objSignatureObject.ReplyMessageSignature = "Firma Corporativa XXXXX"
 objDoc.Saved = True
 objWord.Quit
```

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente pero necesito tener un salto de línea entre la imagen y el texto de aviso de privacidad, ¿De que forma sería?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La verdad no se mucho de este lenguaje pero se me ocurre que agregando `HTML (</br>)` antes del texto en el que ocupas el salto de linea o igual un `\r\n`

Comment: No amigo, eso no funciona pero gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tenía mal colocado `TypeParagraph()`, la forma correcta es ponerlo antes de la línea donde se quiere hacer el salto de línea, en este caso, es antes del texto  *"El aviso de priv..."*, yo lo tenía antes y por eso no me respetaba el salto de línea, queda de la siguiente manera:

```
objSelection.TypeParagraph()
objSelection.TypeText "El Aviso de Privacidad de XXXXXX, está disponible en "
...
..
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]